# in Dart, using Mirrors, how would you call a class's static method from an instance of the class?

Tags: class, reflection, static, dart, dart-mirrors

if I have an instance, and I know the instance's class contains a static method named `statFn()`, how do I call `statFn()` from the instance?

for example,

```dart
abstract class Junk {
  ...
}
class Hamburger extends Junk {
  static bool get lettuce => true;
  ...
}
class HotDog extends Junk {
  static bool get lettuce => false;
  ...
}

Junk food; // either Hamburger or Hotdog

// how do you get lettuce of food's type?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should get you started.
`findStaticAndInvoke()` looks at the class of the provided object and it's subclasses for the static method or getter and invokes it when found.

```dart
library x;

import 'dart:mirrors';

abstract class Junk {
  static void doSomething() {
    print("Junk.doSomething()");
  }
}

class Hamburger extends Junk {
  static bool get lettuce => true;
}

class HotDog extends Junk {
  static bool get lettuce => false;
}

Junk food; // either Hamburger or Hotdog

void main(List<String> args) {
  Junk food = new HotDog();
  findStaticAndInvoke(food, "doSomething");
  findStaticAndInvoke(food, "lettuce");

  food = new Hamburger();
  findStaticAndInvoke(food, "doSomething");
  findStaticAndInvoke(food, "lettuce");
}

void findStaticAndInvoke(o, String name) {
  ClassMirror r = reflect(o).type;
  MethodMirror sFn;
  var s = new Symbol(name);

  while (sFn == null && r != null) {
    sFn = r.staticMembers[s];
    if(sFn != null) {
      break;
    }
    r = r.superclass;
  }

  if(sFn != null) {
    if(sFn.isGetter) {
      print(r.getField(s).reflectee);
    }
    else {
      r.invoke(s, []);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When you convert such code to JavaScript tree-shaking may drop some functions because it cant recognize references like `new Symbol('someMethod'). To prevent this you can use `@MirrorsUsed` or `@reflectable`. If you get errors like `xxx does not have a method named yyy' in JavaScript this is probably the cause.

Comment: would you use @reflectable at the top of the class declaration?

Comment: `@MirrorsUsesd` before the `import 'dart:mirrors';` or @reflectable before the method/field.