# Populating a parent field dynamically in Dart

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

I'm creating objects dynamically from Map data, populating fields for matching key names.  The problem comes when fields are defined on the parent, where attempting to set a value on a parent field  produces the error:

```
No static setter 'name' declared in class 'Skill'.

  NoSuchMethodError : method not found: 'name'
```

code:

```dart
class Resource {
  String name;
  String description;

  Resource.map(Map data)
  {
    ClassMirror c = reflectClass(runtimeType);
    ClassMirror thisType = c;
    while(c != null)
    {
      for (var k in c.declarations.keys) {
        print('${MirrorSystem.getName(k)} : ${data[MirrorSystem.getName(k)]}');
        if(data[MirrorSystem.getName(k)] != null)
        {
          thisType.setField(k, data[MirrorSystem.getName(k)]);        
        }
      }
      c = c.superclass;
    }
  }
}

class Skill extends Resource
{
  Skill.map(data) : super.map(data);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a `ObjectMirror` to set a field on your object. Your code tries to set a field on `ClassMirror` which tries to define a *static variable*.

```dart
class Resource {
  String name;
  String description;

  Resource.map(Map data)
  {
    ObjectMirror o = reflect(this);  // added
    ClassMirror c = reflectClass(runtimeType);
    ClassMirror thisType = c;
    while(c != null)
    {
      for (var k in c.declarations.keys) {
        print('${MirrorSystem.getName(k)} : ${data[MirrorSystem.getName(k)]}');
        if(data[MirrorSystem.getName(k)] != null)
        {
          // replace "thisType" with "o"
          o.setField(k, data[MirrorSystem.getName(k)]);
        }
      }
      c = c.superclass;
    }
  }
}

class Skill extends Resource
{
  Skill.map(data) : super.map(data);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to get all the inherited fields without walking the hierarchy?

Comment: I think you have to walk through the hierarchy.

Answer (score 3):

Static methods/fields are not inherited in Dart.
There were already some discussions about that behavior here.
You can take a look at the answer to this question [in Dart, using Mirrors, how would you call a class's static method from an instance of the class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20743346)

If the methods/fields you try to access are not static please provide more code (the classes/objects you are reflecting about)