# How to pass a type to a function and invoke its static methods?

Tags: dart

Suppose T1, T2 and T3 all have static functions f1, f2, f3 that I'd like to call generically.

How can something like this easily be achieved?

```
class T1 {
  static f1(i) => i+1;
  static f2(i) => i+1;
  static f3(i) => i+1;
}

class T2 {
  static f1(i) => i+2;
  static f2(i) => i+2;
  static f3(i) => i+2;
}

class T3 {
  static f1(i) => i+3;
  static f2(i) => i+3;
  static f3(i) => i+3;
}

callGenerically(dynamic type) {
  print(type);

  type.f1(type.f2(type.f3));
}

main() {
  callGenerically(T1);
  callGenerically(T2);
  callGenerically(T3);
}
```

This prints T1, so it is getting the type. Just don't know how to invoke the static functions on it. Is mirrors an option or requirement even though it is expected f1,f2,f3 exist?

Comment: I just want to say that this — in general — is not a good pattern. If you're not _forced_ to do this (or if this isn't just a language experiment), try choosing a different approach, without `dart:mirrors`.

Comment: Why having 3 `typedef`s does not work in your scenario? You could pass 3 (function) references and compose the way you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this using `dart:mirrors`:

```dart
reflectType(SomeClass).invoke(#someStaticMethod, []).reflectee;
```

Now if you wrap that in a helper method "`call`", then `callGenerically` can look like:

```dart
callGenerically(Type type, num arg) =>
    call(type, #f1, [call(type, #f2, [call(type, #f3, [arg])])]);
```

You can see a full example in [this DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/9e60b2804171e20d793d657149fdd365).

Note that

- **This is an anti-pattern and it's better to communicate to Dart's type system what methods are expected to exist. If you know the classes have the same API, just use ordinary polymorphism instead of reflection, like in Jonas' answer.**
- Using `dart:mirrors` precludes tree-shaking in dart2js, producing bloated JS.
- The call to `f3` needs an argument, hence the second arg in `callGenerically`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess for this to work without `dart:mirrors`, [metaclasses](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_enhancement_proposals/issues/4) would need to land.

The code in [in Dart, using Mirrors, how would you call a class's static method from an instance of the class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20743346/in-dart-using-mirrors-how-would-you-call-a-classs-static-method-from-an-insta) should get you started - not sure if it still works the same, it's quite some time I posted the answer :D

Comment: This is helpful - but I don't want to construct an instance that is otherwise  not necessary just get mirrors to call a static function. Besides there may be no guarantee T has a default ctor. I had not seen the metaclass discussion and that looks like what I would be after.

Comment: I haven't used `dart:mirrors` for a long time and don't remember details.

Comment: In `dart:mirrors` you will want `reflectType(T1).invoke(#f1, [])` as in http://dartpad.dartlang.org/cd1bb844eaa48b210e53cd0b7b31a1e0

Answer (score 1):

This construct picks the static functions. Maybe there are others.

```
typedef int fadd_t(final int i);

abstract class T {
  final fadd_t f1;
  final fadd_t f2;
  final fadd_t f3;

  T(final this.f1, final this.f2, final this.f3);

  int fsum(final int i){
     return f1(f2(f3(i)));
  }
}

class T1 extends T {

  T1() : super(lf1, lf2, lf3){
  }

  static lf1(i) => i+1;
  static lf2(i) => i+1;
  static lf3(i) => i+1;
}

class T2 extends T {

  T2() : super(lf1, lf2, lf3){
  }

  static lf1(i) => i+2;
  static lf2(i) => i+2;
  static lf3(i) => i+2;
}

callGenerically(final T t, final int i) {
  return t.f1(t.f2(t.f3(i)));
}


main() {

    T1 t1 = new T1();
    print('T1 fsum(1) : ' + t1.fsum(1).toString() );
    print('T1 callGenerically(1) : ' + callGenerically(t1, 1).toString() );

    T2 t2 = new T2();
    print('T2 fsum(1) : ' + t2.fsum(1).toString() );
    print('T2 callGenerically(1) : ' + callGenerically(t2, 1).toString() );
}
```

T1 fsum(1) : 4

T1 callGenerically(1) : 4

T2 fsum(1) : 7

T2 callGenerically(1) : 7